# Galaxy S2 not charging

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, charging

Galaxy S2 not charging tried usb and wall charger, initially I had this problem I removed and put the battery back it and it then began to charge however on next charge it stopped in mid charge ( normally leave phone off when charging).. now its just a lump of black plastic.
I tried removing the battery while plugged in , then powering on immediately after putting the battery back in , cleaning the port, even reboot does not work ...any suggestions...my guess I need a new battery although it is less than 12 months.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't change anything on your phone and it's still under warranty (you said less than 12 months), the easiest solution would be to take your phone to a Samsung service center. They might change your battery for free.

Answer (score 1):

2 possible causes:

1. Faulty battery
2. USB port defect

Both of these are hardware problems. To be frank, battery charging problems seldom have to do with software defects, so the best thing is to send it to the nearest Samsung service centre and get it fixed, or maybe even a replacement.